# Why doesn't autopagerize work on meta and stack apps sites?

Tags: feature-request, specific-question

I was reading [Scott Hanselman's Post on AutoPagerize](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InfiniteScrollWebSitesViaAutoPagerizeHackyButTheBeginningOfSomethingCool.aspx) and I installed it for use with Google Chrome.  It appears to work as expected on all of the sites except for Meta and Stack Apps.  Can support for extensions like AutoPagerize be added to Meta and Stack Apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't make any sense, as all the sites are running on the same engine.

The only difference is the CSS and images (and a few under the hood configuration parameters and settings).

Comment: I agree that it doesn't make any sense.  I noticed the behavior on the unanswered questions list as the Autopagerize extension seems to "append" pages on all of the sites except for meta and stack apps.  I would have assumed it was an issue with Autopagerize but knowing that all of the sites run on the same engine I would have thought that I would have seen the same behavior on all of the sites.

Comment: Autopagerize appears to be functioning as expected now on Meta and StackApps.  The two sites had not been added to the "database of sites" located here: http://wedata.net/databases/AutoPagerize/items
I added entries for both Meta and StackApps.